# handlebars with webpack - variables is not passing into custom helper

Tags: javascript, webpack, handlebars.js, helper

I have files as below:

```
/assets
|- /templates
   |- /helpers
      |- iff.js
   |- /partials
      |- head.hbs
   |- chat.hbs
   |- index.hbs
|- /public
   |- chat.html <---- exported by webpack build command
   |- index.html <---- exported by webpack build command
|- webpack.config.js
```

in chat.hbs, I include head.hbs like this:

```
{{>head pageName='Chat Room'}}
```

in index.hbs, I include head.hbs like this:

```
{{>head}}
```

in head.hbs, I call custom helper iff as below:

```
{{#iff pageName '!==' undefined}}
   <span> {{pageName}}</span>
{{/iff}}
```

the custom helper iff.js as below:

```
module.exports = (a, operator, b, opts)=> {
    var bool = false;
    switch(operator) {
       case '==':
           bool = a == b;
           break;
       case '!==':
            bool = a !== b;
            break;
       case '>':
           bool = a > b;
           break;
       case '<':
           bool = a < b;
           break;
       default:
           throw "Unknown operator " + operator;
    }

    if (bool) {
        return opts.fn(this);
    } else {
        return opts.inverse(this);
    }
}
```

and to setup custom helpers, webpack.config.js as below:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': [
            './assets/js/app.js'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'js/[name].min.js'
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    },
   plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './assets/templates/index.hbs',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './assets/templates/chat.hbs',
            filename: 'chat.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(hbs|handlebars)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "handlebars-loader",
                options: {
                    partialDirs: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/templates/partials'),
                    knownHelpersOnly: false,
                    helperDirs: path.resolve(__dirname, "./assets/templates/helpers")
                }
              }]
        }]
    }  
};
```

The result is: 
for index.html, elements between {{#iff}} and {{/iff}} block do not render which is good.
but for chat.html, the block between {{#iff}} and {{/iff}} rendered without passing variable pageName in.

I know I could custom made a helper and don't use {{/iff}} structure instead.

But I wonder is there any way to make it works as same as handlebars on the server-side node.js.